# How can I get the details of currently playing song in miniplayer?

Tags: flutter, just-audio

I am working on a music player app in flutter.
I fetch the songs from devices using on_audio_query package and display them in listview. When I click on a song, i set the plylist of all songs and play the one thats clicked using just_audio package like this.

```
                 await player.setAudioSource(
                  ConcatenatingAudioSource(
                    useLazyPreparation: true,
                    shuffleOrder: DefaultShuffleOrder(),
                    children: allSongsList! // allSongsList is the list of 
                     songs(on_audio_query)
                        .map((songModel) =>
                            AudioSource.uri(Uri.parse(songModel.data)))
                        .toList(),
                  ),
                  initialIndex: index, // Listview Index
                  initialPosition: Duration.zero);

                  await item.player.play();
```

I want to show miniplayer at the bottom only when there is a song playing(paused),refresh the song descriptions,how do I get the song description(Artist/song)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will let you the implementation of the mini player widget for you, however, I will consider that I have a `shouldMiniPlayerBeVisible`, in the `Scaffold` of your page:

First, declare and initialize a `shouldMiniPlayerBeVisible`  variable that will manage the show/hide of the mini player:

```
bool shouldMiniPlayerBeVisible = false;
```

and a `currentAudio` which will take the song and pass it in the mini player.

```
YourAudioModel currentAudio = YourAudioModel();
```

Here, I supposed that I have a simple `YourAudioModel` which will hold information about audio such as title, description, length, URL (or local) path ...

I recommend not setting it to `null` initially , you can initialize it with a placeholder `YourAudioModel` audio model that has some dummy data, or loading data information for example...

now in your Scaffold:

```
Scaffold(
floatingActionButton: Visibility(
  visible: shouldMiniPlayerBeVisible, 
  child: shouldMiniPlayerBeVisible(songToPlay: currentAudio),
  ),
),
```

I will consider that you are using a `StatefulWidget`, but the steps are the same as you need just to get the idea of it to implement it in other state management solutions.

in the `initState`, you need to listen to the `playerStateStream` stream like this:

```
player.playerStateStream.listen((state) {
 if (state.playing) {
  shouldMiniPlayerBeVisible = true;
 } else {
 shouldMiniPlayerBeVisible = false;
}
  setState(() {});
 });
```

this basically will track if any audio is playing or not, then show the mini player based on it.

now before your run the `await item.player.play();`, set your `currentAudio` variable to the new audio which is running, you can do it with a function like this:

```
Future<void> playCurrentAudioANdShowItInMiniPlayer(YourAudioModel audio) async {
currentAudio = YourAudioModel;
await item.player.play();
}
```

now from your UI, for each item in `ListView`, you can just call the `playCurrentAudioANdShowItInMiniPlayer` method with its `YourAudioModel`and expect it to work fine.

from here, you should implement the actual mini player widget, and you will need also a custom `Navigator` widget so that mini player will be on the screen even if you navigated to other screens, well I faced this issue before and the [miniplayer](https://pub.dev/packages/miniplayer) worked just really fine and good as I expected, I recommend you to use it.

Comment: appreciate the effort bro !